# Is it possible to get the record ID and details of a Lead inserted through web2lead form?

Tags: web2lead

Basically I need to create a web application that contains a web to lead form. Upon submission of the Lead, I need to get the record ID and details of that Lead in my web application, which is obviously external to Salesforce.com. Any thoughts how I can go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Config solutions**

You could define a workflow rule?

1. Firing condition would be on lead creation (when certain criteria are met like [stuff defined here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_leads_what_status_is.htm) + any fields you decide to have in the form)
2. Action would be an [outbound message](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging.htm) flying back to your website.
3. If not an outbound message - maybe an email alert going to dedicated mailbox that's readable by your app.
4. Scheduled report sent to an user whose email happens to be monitored by your website ;)

**Coding solutions - SF as the actor**

1. REST callout to your site, defined as `@future` in the "after insert" trigger on Lead.
2. Scheduled batch job running hourly? daily? sending Ids of recently created leads.

**Coding solutions - your page as the actor**

All above are asynchronous, you don't wait for the answer, you get the message / email some time later. Means you'd have to store "unmatched leads" somewhere.

If that's unacceptable - you could ditch the web2lead process and create your own integration (via SOAP or REST), there are high chances you'll find something for yourself at http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Data_Integration. Basically the [`create()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_create.htm) call would return to you with either the error or lead's Id...

Or just ask by sending a query ;) Or being notified via Streaming API ;) Plenty of options really.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm going to have a look at these and see which ones work for me. The thing is I basically need an "instant" response to say who the Lead was assigned to.

Comment: Outbound message, email etc should include the field because http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm says the assignment rules are before workflows; but it'll be async. The SOAP/REST API call will out of the box return you only the generated lead's Id. You'd have to query (check `retrieve` call) for the Owner yourself... One more option - build a webservice you'd be calling from your app, there you'll have full control over what's returned.

Comment: Last thing - is it really you (=your app) that needs to know the owner? or is it the lead? Web2Lead offers option to send them an email based on email template. So you could pull of something like "welcome, blah blah, your account manager will be John Doe..."

Comment: basically it's a call script and the agent who's submitting the form needs to know who the Lead was assigned to instantly, while they are still on the line with the customer (they don't have SFDC licenses)

Comment: Last idea I promise :P Visualforce page exposed as Site. Doesn't need PHP/C#/Java/etc coding skills or learning of integration API. You could easily check in SF for duplicates, display their related data maybe...

Comment: I actually love that last idea. Seems such less effort and pain as opposed to the other options. So just a visualforce page as site? and then give them access to see the Lead page / details?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12476/discussion-between-eyescream-and-user988)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the SOAP or REST API. The web-to-lead form in salesforce.com doesn't actually generate the lead "immediately" but places it in a queue for asynchronous processing, thus no information about the lead is available until some time later.