# In site.com, how to get the LeadID returned after insertion with a form?

Tags: site.com, web2lead

I am setting up a site.com site with a form connected to the Lead object, for public web Lead insertion. How can I get the Lead ID in the site.com page after insertion?

Answer (score 0):

Standard web2lead does not support this.

See [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/23979/865) for some alternatives.